Virial Theorem: Application to simplify a PDE
Let
$$\frac{d^2\phi}{dt^2}=-\frac{dV(\phi)}{d\phi}$$
be be a PDE in $\phi(t)$, $V(\phi)$ should be physically thought as a potential. In this answer isclaimed that by means of virial theorem the above PDE can be transformed into first-order equation
$$\frac{d\phi}{d\tau}=\sqrt{2V(\phi)}.$$
Could somebody elaborate how to achieve this? Especially how the virial theorem is going to be involved appears to be obscure to me here.
ADDED LATER: Here some failed ideas:
Firstly one shall integrate $\frac{d^2\phi}{dt^2}=-\frac{dV(\phi)}{d\phi}$ over $t$ to get ( up to constant) $\frac{d\phi}{dt}=- \int \frac{dV(\phi(t))}{d\phi}dt +C= -\int \frac{\frac{dV(\phi(t))}{dt}}{\frac{d\phi}{dt}}dt +C$ (*). (...Here I just used $\frac{dV(\phi(t))}{dt}= \frac{dV(\phi(t))}{d\phi} \cdot \frac{d\phi}{dt}$ assuming time dependence of $V$ sits only in $\phi(t)$, otherwise it will become unlikely difficult)
Energy conservation tells $Kin(t) +V(t)=E:=C'$ (sum of kinetic & potential term constant), so $\frac{dV(\phi(t))}{dt}= \frac{dKin(\phi(t))}{dt}=M (\frac{d\phi}{dt}) \cdot \frac{d^2\phi}{dt^2}$ (...here exploited that $Kin(x) \sim x^2$),
so right side of (*) becomes (after dividing out $\frac{d\phi}{dt}$ we would get back $-\int M \frac{d^2\phi}{dt^2}dt= -M\frac{d\phi}{dt}$, but that's absurd looking at LHS of (*). Hot sure how to "repair" it and as stated above how virial thm would be involved.
Expressed with homogeneous potential of shape $V(x)= c \cdot x^n$, VT reads as $2 \cdot \int Kin(t) dt= n \cdot \int V(x(t))dt$, but I don't think that such homogenity assumption for $V$ was made in quoted answer, so I don't know.

Virial I don't know but energy conservation seems plausible. I didn't try though

Yes it works I think (up to integration constants at least). Start from energy conservation, try to obtain a first order equation for $(d\phi/dt)^2$ and you should be good

You need to replace $V$ in side the square root by $E-V$ with $E$ an integration constant (physically the total energy).

@Syrocco: I'm not sure if I got the idea, here how I proceed: Firstly one shall integrate $\frac{d^2\phi}{dt^2}=-\frac{dV(\phi)}{d\phi}$ over $t$ to get ( up to constant) $\frac{d\phi}{dt}=- \int \frac{dV(\phi(t))}{d\phi}dt +C= -\int \frac{\frac{dV(\phi(t))}{dt}}{\frac{d\phi}{dt}}dt +C$ (*). Energy concervation tells $Kin(t) +V(t)=C'$ (sum of kinetic & potential term constant), so $\frac{dV(\phi(t))}{dt}= \frac{dKin(\phi(t))}{dt}=M (\frac{d\phi}{dt}) \cdot \frac{d^2\phi}{dt^2}$, so right

side of (*) becomes (after dividing out $\frac{d\phi}{dt}$ we would get back $-\int M \frac{d^2\phi}{dt^2}dt= -M\frac{d\phi}{dt}$, but that's absurd looking at LHS of (*). Could you give an advice how to "repair" to approach and/ or what I did wrong there?

@user267839 No nevermind, as LPZ points out the total energy (or integration constant) is important. From the conservation of energy: $(d\phi/dt)^2/2+V=E$, thus $d\phi/dt=\sqrt{2(E-V)} $. You might be able to get rid of the E by an appropriate change of variable  from $t$ to $\tau$. Possibly also, since we are starting in local minimum and and that it might be physically relevant to look for zero kinetic energy initial condition, E could be 0. Which still lefts us with a sign issue, that could again be fixed by a change of variable

For a non-trivial finite energy solution of the EOM of a one-dimensional system you can show that there is a kind of virial law. You can derive this by observing that potential and kinetic energy scale in the opposite way under dilation and balance each other out. You have $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2}\dot\phi^2dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}V(x)dx.$$ Additionally, you have that $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\dot\phi\pm\sqrt{V(\phi)}\right)^2dx\geq0.$$ It follows that $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2}\dot\phi^2+V(x)dx\geq\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\pm \dot\phi\sqrt{2V(\phi)}dx$$ and $$E\geq\mid{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\dot\phi\sqrt{2V(\phi)}dx}\mid  =  \mid{\int_{\phi_-}^{\phi_+}\sqrt{2V(\phi)}d\phi}\mid.$$ Due to the fact that we can always fix $V(\phi)\geq0$ there exists a superpotential $V(\phi)=\frac{1}{2}(\frac{dW}{d\phi})^2$ and we find that $E\geq \mid{W(\phi_+)-W(\phi_-)}\mid$. So the Euclidean action can be written as $$E=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \dot\phi^2\mp\left(\frac{dW}{d\phi}\right)^2 dx\pm\left(W(\phi_+)-W(\phi_-)\right).$$ The EOM thus are $$\dot\phi=\pm\frac{dW}{d\phi}=\pm\sqrt{2V(\phi)}$$ $$\lim_{x\to\pm\infty} \phi= \phi_{\pm} \hspace{1mm} or \hspace{1mm}\phi_{\mp}$$
This observasion was first made by Bogomolny and independently by Prasad and Sommerfeld. Therefore such bounds are called BPS-bounds. They are satisfied also by Yang-Mills instantons. From this perspective the model looks like a Lifshitz-field theory.
One can also use the following trick: Consider the nonlinear Klein-Gordon equation $$\partial_\mu\phi\partial^\mu\phi+\frac{dV}{d\phi}=0$$ and make the ansatz of plane-waves $$\phi(x,t)=f(x-ut)=f(\eta).$$ Then you get $$\frac{d^2f}{d\eta^2}=\gamma^2\frac{dV}{df}$$ where $\gamma=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}$. Now multiply both sides with $\frac{df}{d\eta}$ and you get $$\frac{df}{d\eta}=\pm\gamma\sqrt{2V(f)}$$

If you use \left( and \right), you can size your parenthesis more appropriately as it's a little difficult to read currently in the first few equations

Could you indicate how you deduce from prev considerations that the action functional must be $E=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \dot\phi^2\mp(\frac{dW}{d\phi})^2dx+(W(\phi_+)-W(\phi_-))$? Before you reached a priori only an estimation $E\geq \mid{W(\phi_+)-W(\phi_-)}\mid$?

@user267839 You simply complete the square in the Euclidean action $$E=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2}\dot\phi^2+V(\phi)dx$$ and you get the boundary term derived beforehand, which does not effect the equations of motion.

The instantons are the solutions for which this bound is saturated.

Right, I see now that part. But about what I'm still wondering about is that following your derivation of the EOM in the middle $\dot\phi=\pm\frac{dW}{d\phi}=\pm\sqrt{2V(\phi)}$ you seemingly nowhere made explicit usage of virial theorem as you claimed in the other answer that it should be involved. If I understood you correctly, all you used there was writing down the Euclidiean action $E=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2}\dot\phi^2+V(\phi)dx$, reexpressing it by means of completing the

square with boundary term $\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \dot\phi^2\mp\left(\frac{dW}{d\phi}\right)^2 dx\pm\left(W(\phi_+)-W(\phi_-)\right)$, and deriving that these boundary term satisfies estimation $E\geq \mid{W(\phi_+)-W(\phi_-)}\mid$. So far I can follow your derivation you nowhere invoked the virial theorem as auxilary tool. Or do I overlooked where it actually goes in in crucial way?
